# jQuery data attribute selector for closest parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, closest

My code have data attribute set for many elements (Not For All Elements) in below manner.

1. `<div id='dvStorage' data-testing='storage_div'>`

And, for some of the elements (Not For All Elements) data attribute is set with below approach.

2. `$("#ElementID").data("testing", "data value");`

Now, the problem comes. When any button on the document is clicked, I need to find its parent having data attribute (testing) is set. As mentioned, all elements do not have data attribute, so I need to travese upwards in the hierarchy until the expected element is found.

For #1 approach, `$("#buttonID").closest("[data-testing]")` works. But not for #2 approach.

For #2 approach, I need to iterate through button `parents()` and verify if it has `.data("testing")` or not. I need to avoid this iteration. And have one common approach that works for #1 and #2.

Here, it is not required to verify value of data-testing, but to get the first parent in hierarchy having "testing" set as its data attribute.

Thanks in advance.

[JSFIDDLE Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/murarid/L8d3kk2e/2/)

Comment: Why don't you show us a DEMO Fiddle?? With complete code

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You only have two choices:

As you mentioned in the first choice, you have to iterate through all of the elements because `$("#ElementID").data("testing", "data value");` will NOT update the attribute `data-testing`, because the value is stored internally in the DOM.

The second method is to provide add another class that can be used in the selector:

```
$("#ElementID").data("testing", "data value").addClass("has-testing");
```

Thus your new selector would be:

```
$("#buttonID").closest("[data-testing], .has-testing");
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/0yoe0rq7/)

Answer (score 2):

try this (work for #2): [data-selector](https://api.jqueryui.com/data-selector/)

```
e.g: $('[data-testing] , :data(testing)')
```

Comment: That's pretty awesome, too bad it's in jQueryUI and not in the core jQuery.  Seems extremely useful outside of UI.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(this).parents("[data-testing]:first");
```

where $(this) will be the current clicked element inside the click handler.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**  `$("#buttonID").closest(["data-testing"])` just change  to following:

```
$("#buttonID").closest("[data-testing]");
```

or use `$(this).parents("[data-testing]")`  for your choice

**[2nd demo](http://jsfiddle.net/on24Lzxj/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can try below solution:

```
$("body *[data-testing]:first");
```

for your reference: http://jsfiddle.net/on24Lzxj/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting `data-testing` through `.data()`, you can use `attr()`:

```
$("#div1").attr("data-testing", "div1_Data");
```

This will add the attribute and value to the element.

Then your normal selector should work:

```
$("#buttonID").closest("[data-testing]")
```

**Edit based on comments:**

Settings attributes using `.attr()` and getting them using `.data()` can be problematic (as evident by Eriks fiddle-example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bckq2uv1/1/)), since the latter only checks the actual element attribute once.

I would suggest to use `.attr()` when both setting and getting, but since the implementation could not be changed this is not an option in this case.

I'll leave my answer here anyway, as I would still recommend it if this was not the case.

Comment: Thanks Mackan. But, the question was with .data() only, and i could not change the implementation.

Comment: This also will be hit or miss.  `.data()` reads are cached after the first read, so any `attr()` update after the first won't be read by `.data()`.  [JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/bckq2uv1/)

Comment: @ErikPhilips You're adding attr oddly in your example. You never added `data-`, or am I misunderstanding? Uodated example: http://jsfiddle.net/bckq2uv1/1/

Comment: @Mackan nice catch!  Yes my example is incorrect.  But you'll notice how the `.data()` does not return the expected *larry* on the second read :)

Comment: @ErikPhilips yes - I was on my phone last time so I didn't have a very good overview. It is indeed odd behaviour (according to me), but then again I would just use `attr()` straight through. `data()` seems a bit .. touchy :)